# Oracle - Distributing one row value across rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

As mention in the attached file. I need to distribute value in column 'B' as less or equal to column A.
Now for A>B Case 2, I need distributing of 65 as 44,16,5 but getting like 44,16,20.

[image]

Comment: Your results assume an ordering on the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column to specify the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

SQL table represent *unordered* sets.  But your results assume an ordering.  I will assume there is an ordering column and represent it as `?`.

This is a cumulative sum problem -- with arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when b >= running_a then a
             when b >= running_a - a then b - (running_a - a)
             else 0
        end) as new_a
from (select t.*, sum(a) over (order by ?) as running_a
      from t
     ) t
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e8f1e11f7af423485c7f25349644cae5) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood the question.

```
SQL> with test (a, b) as
  2  -- sample data
  3    (select 0, 60 from dual union all
  4     select 88, 0 from dual union all
  5     select 32, 0 from dual union all
  6     select 7,  0 from dual
  7    ),
  8  -- query you need begins here
  9  temp as
 10    (select a,
 11            max(b) over (order by null) b
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  select
 15    x.a,
 16    case when x.a = 0 then y.b
 17         else case when x.a > y.b then y.b
 18              else x.b
 19         end
 20    end b
 21  from test x left join temp y on x.a = y.a
 22  order by x.a;

         A          B
---------- ----------
         0         60
         7          0
        32          0
        88         60

SQL>
```

---

```
SQL> with test (a, b) as
  2  -- sample data
  3    (select 0, 75 from dual union all
  4     select 21, 0 from dual union all
  5     select 12, 0 from dual union all
  6     select 42, 0 from dual
  7    ),
  8  -- query you need begins here
  9  temp as
 10    (select a,
 11            max(b) over (order by null) b
 12     from test
 13    )
 14  select
 15    x.a,
 16    case when x.a = 0 then y.b
 17         else x.a
 18    end b
 19  from test x left join temp y on x.a = y.a
 20  order by x.a;

         A          B
---------- ----------
         0         75
        12         12
        21         21
        42         42

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks,

But for below case

 IN   OUT  
A > B A B  A B 
 0 65  0 60 
 44 0  44 44 
 16 0  16 16 
 20 0  20 5

How can I assign if something is remaining? Currently output is giving me 20.

Comment: You're welcome, but - this is unreadable. Edit the original question and post data in there.

Comment: I don't think that SQL resolves initial question. it works only when sum(A) equal to 1st line in B...

Comment: Maybe, @are. As I said, that's how I understood it.

Comment: Thanks.The earlier SQL was working, I edited the question afterward.